# Qt C++ не видит стандартные библиотеки C++

Tags: c++, qt, модули

пишу программу в Qt.
И при добавлении в нее модулей выходит следующее.
Допустим все знают string.h, стандартная библиотека c++.
В ней определенно  strcmp. Если я допустим в visual studio работаю с strcmp ничего не добавляя, это не вызывает никаких проблем, ибо vs находит strcmp в string h.
А в qt пишет "no matching function for call "strcmp"
так же и c compare.
Вопрос почему qt не хочет видеть стандартные значения библиотек с++

Comment: strcmp это из стандартной библиотеки си . В с++ нужно подключать cstring

Comment: @mik.ov ну написал я #include <cstring> всеравно пишет что не находит strcmp. Вообще бред какой то. Visual Studio не пишет никаких ошибок, а этот Qt все в ошибках кроет

Comment: как понять "Пишу программу в Qt" ?? Может быть "Пишу программу в QtCreator" или "Пишу программу, используя фреймворк Qt"